# Make conditions in SQL Server SELECT request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get your minds with my question. I'm using SQL Server and I have a SELECT request. In this request, I wold like to make a condition.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
        Workflow.Id                      as Id,
        ...,

        SELECT CAST (
            CASE WHEN @CodeAlgo = 'BQ'
            THEN
                (SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel) FROM DonneesFinancieresComplementaires WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) as TopConfidentiel
            ELSE
                (SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel) FROM DonneesFinancieres WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) as TopConfidentiel
            END)
    FROM Workflow
```

SQL Server Management Studio says me :

> Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.

I have to write my condition to a different way ?

I tried something like this too:

```
SELECT
        Workflow.Id                      as Id,
        ...,

        IF @CodeAlgo = 'BQ'
            BEGIN
                (SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel) FROM DonneesFinancieresComplementaires WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) as TopConfidentiel
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                (SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel) FROM DonneesFinancieres WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) as TopConfidentiel
            END
    FROM Workflow
```

But same thing.

Comment: If the first statement you have a `SELECT` in the middle of your `SELECT`; you can't start a new `SELECT` statement without finishing the first (unless it is a subquery). `IF`, on the other had, is a logical flow operator, not an expression; it can't be used within a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Coskun points out, you don't need `SELECT` and the correct logic in SQL Server is `CASE`.

That said, in any query that references more than one table, you should get in the habit of qualifying *all* column names.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT wf.Id,  -- no AS is needed, the name is "id"
       . . .,
       (CASE WHEN @CodeAlgo = 'BQ'
             THEN (SELECT MAX(dfc.TopConfidentiel
                   FROM DonneesFinancieresComplementaires dfc
                   WHERE dfc.IdWorkflow = wf.Id
                  ) 
             ELSE (SELECT MAX(df.TopConfidentiel)
                   FROM DonneesFinancieres df
                   WHERE df.IdWorkflow = wf.Id
                  ) 
        END) as TopConfidentiel
FROM Workflow wf;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this (If cast is necessary, you can cast your TopConfidentiel field in your select clause) :

```
SELECT
    Workflow.Id                      as Id,
    ...,

        CASE 

        WHEN @CodeAlgo = 'BQ'

        THEN
            (SELECT 
              CAST(MAX(TopConfidentiel) AS yourtype) 
             --If CAST is necessary, you can use this for exemple CAST(MAX(TopConfidentiel) AS VARCHAR(10)).
             FROM DonneesFinancieresComplementaires 
             WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) 
        ELSE
           (SELECT 
             CAST(MAX(TopConfidentiel) AS yourtype) 
            FROM DonneesFinancieres 
            WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id) 
        END

        AS TopConfidentiel


FROM Workflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (not tested)

```
SELECT Workflow.Id AS Id, 
       CAST((CASE
                 WHEN @CodeAlgo = 'BQ'
                 THEN
(
    SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel)
    FROM DonneesFinancieresComplementaires
    WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id
)
                 ELSE
(
    SELECT MAX(TopConfidentiel)
    FROM DonneesFinancieres
    WHERE IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id
)
             END) AS VARCHAR) AS TopConfidentiel
FROM Workflow;
```

Alternatively,

```
IF(@CodeAlgo = 'BQ')
    BEGIN
        SELECT Workflow.Id AS Id, 
               MAX(TopConfidentiel) AS TopConfidentiel
        FROM Workflow
             INNER JOIN DonneesFinancieresComplementaires ON IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id
        GROUP BY Workflow.Id;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT Workflow.Id AS Id, 
               MAX(TopConfidentiel) AS TopConfidentiel
        FROM Workflow
             INNER JOIN DonneesFinancieres ON IdWorkflow = Workflow.Id
        GROUP BY Workflow.Id;
    END;
```